# input(password) onblur javascript bug internet explorer 7 and 8

Tags: javascript

here is my input javascript inline code

```
<input type="text" value="Please type username here..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Please type username here...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Please type username here...';}" name="name1" id="username">
```

it works in mozilla, IE9 Chrome but not working in IE7 and IE8, it shows text instead of password(asterisk ) or hidden value.

Comment: I've copied and pasted it in a file, tested and working in IE8.

Comment: Likewise. Tested in IE8 and in IE7 mode, works fine in both. Are you sure you copied the right line of code? That is a username field, not password.

Comment: No problems with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ9sP/) in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `placeholder` attribute for this behavior. That way, you won’t need any JavaScript in modern browsers that support this attribute. Then, you can use a polyfill to make it work in IE9 and older browsers.

Your HTML would look like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. myusername" name="username" id="username">
<input type="password" placeholder="e.g. hunter2" name="password" id="password">
```

I made [a `@placeholder` polyfill in jQuery plugin format](http://mths.be/placeholder) that you can use as follows:

```
$('input').placeholder();
```

Here’s a demo: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder As you can see, it handles `textarea`s and password inputs just fine.

Comment: yes thnx buddy, i will try and will sure reply back with result :)